# SQL Server: Compare two columns in two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables (from two different systems) that track the employees' hours. In both tables, the employees enter the date and hours. I need to create an audit report that shows the discrepancy. The report needs to show all the columns and display a null/no match if there is a mismatch. One table might have more/less entries than the other table or even duplicate entries and I need to catch that (two entries on the same day for the same amount of hours in one table). Both tables have UserID that can be joined on.

If there is match based on date and hours, show all the values.
If there is a mismatch based on hours, show null or no match when there is mismatch.
If there is a duplicate entry, like the image below, match the first entry and report the second one as null or no match.

I tried joining the tables based UserID, date, and hours but not able to tell where the mismatch came from.

Table A:

[image]

Table B:

[image]

Left Join on UserID, date, and hours

[image]

Comment: is there no primary key here? i.e. employeeID or something similar? You've showing three screen shots but haven't elaborated to what is the data set, expected results, etc....

Comment: The primary key is the UserID in both tables. The expected result is to show null or no match (or abetter way if you know) if there mismatch when these four columns compared

Comment: You seem to need some help here but you have forgotten to provide any information as to what you want. What do you mean by "mismatch"??? We can't see your screen or read your mind. Give us some details and we can help. As it sits right now all anybody can do is guess.

Comment: If there a date entry in the second table and no same date entry in the first table that is a mismatch, or same date entry in both tables bit different hours entered.

Comment: So use a left join between table1 and table2 on date and TotalHours.

Comment: I tried left join, but it only shows null if there is no entry in table B. Also, if you take a look at entry 8/1/2017, there are 4 entries in table A and 3 in table B (two of them are same date and same hours) so we need to identify that as a mismatch. Also, what would happen if there is an entry in table B lets say 7/29/2017 but not in table A so the left join will not show that. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @table1 table
(
    userid int,
    entry_date date,
    [hours] varchar(10)
)

declare @table2 table
(
    userid int,
    entry_date datetime,
    [hours] varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO @table1
select 1,'8/14/2017','10:00'
INSERT INTO @table1
select 2,'8/14/2017','5:00'
INSERT INTO @table1
select 2,'8/14/2017','5:00'
INSERT INTO @table1
select 2,'8/14/2017','5:00'
INSERT INTO @table1
select 2,'8/14/2017','5:00'
INSERT INTO @table1
select 3,'8/14/2017','5:00'
INSERT INTO @table1
select 3,'8/14/2017','6:00'
INSERT INTO @table1
select 3,'8/14/2017','6:00'
INSERT INTO @table1
select 3,'8/14/2017','6:00'

INSERT INTO @table2
select 1,'8/14/2017','10:00'
INSERT INTO @table2
select 2,'8/14/2017','8:00'
INSERT INTO @table2
select 3,'8/14/2017','6:00'
INSERT INTO @table2
select 4,'8/14/2017','2:00'
INSERT INTO @table2
select 1,'8/14/2017','10:00'
INSERT INTO @table2
select 3,'8/14/2017','6:00'

;WITH CTE_TABLE1 AS
(
    select  t.userid as userid, CAST(t.entry_date as DATE) as entry_date,   t.[hours] as [hours], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.userid, t.entry_date, t.[hours] ORDER BY t.[Hours]) as rnk
    from @Table1 t
), CTE_TABLE2 AS
(
    select  t.userid as userid, CAST(t.entry_date as DATE) as entry_date,   t.[hours] as [hours], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.userid, t.entry_date, t.[hours] ORDER BY t.[Hours]) as rnk
    from @Table2 t
), CTE_MATCHES AS
(
    select  t1.userid as userid, t1.entry_date as entry_date, t1.[hours] as [hours], t1.rnk
    from CTE_TABLE1 t1
    inner join CTE_TABLE2 t2
        on (t1.userid = t2.userid AND t1.entry_date = t2.entry_date AND t1.[hours] = t2.[hours] AND t1.rnk = t2.rnk)
),CTE_MATCH_DUPLICATES AS
(
    select 'Table1MatchDuplicate' as ErrorType, *
    from
    (
        select t.*
        from (select userid, entry_date, [hours], max(rnk) as rnk from CTE_MATCHES group by userid, entry_date, [hours]) m
        inner join CTE_TABLE1 t
            on (t.userid = m.userid AND t.entry_date = m.entry_date AND t.[hours] = m.[hours] AND t.rnk > m.rnk)
    )q
    UNION ALL
    select 'Table2MatchDuplicate' as ErrorType, *
    from
    (
        select t.* 
        from (select userid, entry_date, [hours], max(rnk) as rnk from CTE_MATCHES group by userid, entry_date, [hours]) m
        inner join CTE_TABLE2 t
            on (t.userid = m.userid AND t.entry_date = m.entry_date AND t.[hours] = m.[hours] AND t.rnk > m.rnk)
    )q
)
, CTE_Table1_UNMATCHED AS
(   
    select t.userid, t.entry_date, t.[hours] 
    from @Table1 t
    left outer join CTE_MATCHES m
        on (t.userid = m.userid AND CAST(t.entry_date as DATE) = m.entry_date AND t.[hours] = m.[hours])
    where m.userid is null
), CTE_Table2_UNMATCHED AS
(   
    select t.userid, t.entry_date, t.[hours] 
    from @Table2 t
    left outer join CTE_MATCHES m
        on (t.userid = m.userid AND CAST(t.entry_date as DATE) = m.entry_date AND t.[hours] = m.[hours])
    where m.userid is null
)
select null as ErrorType, userid, entry_date, [hours] from CTE_MATCHES
UNION ALL
select 'Table1Mismatch' as ErrorType, userid, entry_date, [hours] from CTE_Table1_UNMATCHED
UNION ALL
select 'Table2Mismatch' as ErrorType, userid, entry_date, [hours] from CTE_Table2_UNMATCHED
UNION ALL
select ErrorType, userid, entry_date, [hours] from CTE_MATCH_DUPLICATES
order by ErrorType
```

http://rextester.com/UDG95824

if you need to find duplicates that had no matches as well:

```
,CTE_Table1_Unmatched_Duplicates AS
(
    select userid, entry_date, [hours]
    from CTE_Table1_UNMATCHED
    group by userid, entry_date, [hours]
    having count(*) > 1
),CTE_Table2_Unmatched_Duplicates AS
(
    select userid, entry_date, [hours]
    from CTE_Table2_UNMATCHED
    group by userid, entry_date, [hours]
    having count(*) > 1
)
...
UNION
select 'Table1UnmatchedDuplicates' as ErrorType, userid, entry_date, [hours] from CTE_Table1_Unmatched_Duplicates
UNION
select 'Table2UnmatchedDuplicates' as ErrorType, userid, entry_date, [hours] from CTE_Table2_Unmatched_Duplicates
```

http://rextester.com/KEJJF79330

Comment: As for duplicates - do you mean duplicates when the same value is in BOTH tables?  Or do you mean like duplicates as in the same userid and date occurs twice?  Or ...?

Comment: duplicates like entering the same hours for the same date twice in one table like 81/2017 for 8 hrs and another entry for 8/1/2017 for 8 hrs.

Comment: You say 'If there is a duplicate entry, like the image below, match the first entry' is first entry just based on the lowest hour?  a identity field?  something else?  The query I gave above just goes on the lowest hour but doesn't show the other row; I would need to know this to be able to fix it.

Comment: There are two entries on 81/2017 for 8hrs in table B. There is one entry on 8/1/2017 for 8 hrs in table A. We need to identify that second entry in table B as a duplicates or does not have any match in table A as we already matched the first entry of 8 hrs from table B to the only entry of 8 hrs in table A on the same day.

Comment: ok so how would you normally identify which entry is the "second" and which is the "first".  Is there an identity field on the table?

Comment: No there is not. The only primary key is the UserID. Some users try to enter multiple shifts like 8 hours each on the same day so they can get paid overtime. We need to find out these entries. It does not matter which one is the "first" entry or the "second."

Comment: ok, I updated it again - see if that's what you are looking for

Comment: Can we also include userid (1) in the results to show that there is no error. Basically, I want to display all the information matched, mismatched, duplicate, etc..?

Comment: alright, I decided the query before was too complicated and had too many holes so I redid it all.  Now it will just show matches (null errortype), then it will show any duplicates of those same matches, then it will show rows where there was no match from table 1, then rows where there was no match from table 2.  These mismatches might also have dupes among them but you'd need to weed them out (or add more CTE's - I'm not sure if you care since there was no match anyways).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That worked almost, but i have a problem with the "MatchDuplicates" part. Maybe I was not clear, but hoping you can help me out on this. Two entries in table A (8/14/2017 for two hours) and the same exact two entries in table B (8/14/2017 for two hours) should not be displayed as "MatchDuplicates." The ErrorType should display NULLfor them. Is this possible? If there are two exact entries in table A and only one matching entry in table B (or vice versa), then the second entry should be displayed as "MatchDuplicates" and this part is working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151925/discussion-between-element-zero-and-user2536008).